# How to show that $\sin \left(y\right)$ is smaller then $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to show that the

$\lim _{x,y\to 0,0}\left(\frac{x\sin \:\left(y\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)$

equals to 0, using the squeeze theorem so the function is greater then 0 but how do I continue and find what the function is smaller then? I thought about showing that $\sin \left(y\right)$ is smaller then $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ but I can't see how.

Comment: $\sin(y) \le |y| =\sqrt{y^2} \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Answer (score 1):

You could do as $$\sin y \le |y| \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

---

Alternatively (but quite similar),
$$\left|\frac{x\sin y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right| \le \left|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right| \le \frac{\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}$$

Comment: Ok, how do we know that $y≤sqrt(x^2+y^2)$?

Comment: @Ciniminis $y^2 \le x^2+y^2$

Comment: @Ciniminis $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \ge \sqrt{0+y^2} = |y|$

Comment: @Ciniminis Did you satisfy with this answer?